# HttpHostConnectException connection refused ConnectException ErrnoException

Tags: android, json, exception, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

I have a network processes in my application where this exception occurs and I don't know how to fix this. I already applied certain permissions in my manifest, and here is the permissions I applied for my whole app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and the URI I am using is from our server in its global IP address already. It works fine in the browser but in the app, this exception comes out. Here is the stack trace:

```
        08-12 06:15:36.234: W/System.err(862): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080 refused
    08-12 06:15:36.324: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
    08-12 06:15:36.494: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    08-12 06:15:36.594: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    08-12 06:15:36.785: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    08-12 06:15:36.904: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    08-12 06:15:37.014: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    08-12 06:15:37.164: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    08-12 06:15:37.194: W/System.err(862):  at com.android.app.util.Utility.getRequest(Utility.java:42)
    08-12 06:15:37.284: W/System.err(862):  at com.android.app.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:440)
    08-12 06:15:37.404: W/System.err(862):  at com.android.app.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
    08-12 06:15:37.534: W/System.err(862):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    08-12 06:15:37.744: W/System.err(862):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    08-12 06:15:37.804: W/System.err(862):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    08-12 06:15:37.944: W/System.err(862):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    08-12 06:15:38.044: W/System.err(862):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    08-12 06:15:38.164: W/System.err(862):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    08-12 06:15:38.364: W/System.err(862): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /xxx.xx.xxx.xxx (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    08-12 06:15:38.394: W/System.err(862):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    08-12 06:15:38.664: W/System.err(862):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    08-12 06:15:38.845: W/System.err(862):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    08-12 06:15:38.894: W/System.err(862):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    08-12 06:15:39.085: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    08-12 06:15:39.154: W/System.err(862):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    08-12 06:15:39.184: W/System.err(862):  ... 15 more
    08-12 06:15:39.244: W/System.err(862): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    08-12 06:15:39.464: W/System.err(862):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    08-12 06:15:39.774: W/System.err(862):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    08-12 06:15:39.804: W/System.err(862):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    08-12 06:15:39.894: W/System.err(862):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    08-12 06:15:39.984: W/System.err(862):  ... 20 more
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Okay, so here's my Utility:

```
public static String getRequest(String path){
    String url = http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/SampleApi/sample-apis; // Global URL of the API
    String username = "sampleuname";
    String password = "samplepass";

    CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

    try{
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + path);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); // Okay, so the stack trace is pointing in this line

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if(httpEntity != null){ 
            inStream = httpEntity.getContent(); 
            String jsonString = convertStreamToString(inStream);
            return jsonString;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Request NULL";
}
```

and my calling Asynctask:

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
        Log.d(Constant.TAG_LOGIN, path[0]);

        String apiRequestReturn = Utility.getRequest(path[0]); // So here's the other line pointed by the stack trace where I called Utility
        if (apiRequestReturn.equals("")) {
            Log.d(Constant.TAG_LOGIN, "WebService request is null");
            return null;
        } else {
            Log.d(Constant.TAG_LOGIN, "WebService request has data");
            return apiRequestReturn;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(null);

        //JSON PARSING
    }
}
```

Comment: DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183 : can u post this code? & AbstractHttpClient.java

Comment: Does the same request work in the browser?

Comment: @Stacks28 `DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java` belongs to apache: `org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator`

@StefandeBruijn Yes, it works on the browser.

Comment: oh yup m sorry, can u post the code ?

Comment: u r using getMethod for response?right

Comment: output this (url + path) and check(in browser) whether it is providing correct link ? and

Comment: yes, the response is in json

Comment: @Stacks28 It is providing correct link since I used the same URI in the browser and it works fine, but in the application it does not.

Comment: Can u post that link on mail may be I can help

Answer (score 5):

I lso faced the same problem with my device. URI with json response working fine in browser but in device it throws exception. I simply reboot-ed my device then it is working in mobile side. you try to restart your device.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these solution may be among these one solve your issue.

1> check your manifest file internet permission there or not.

2> check your url with browser by rest client and pass the appropriate request.

3> open the url in mobile like:- **http://your ip address/port** that's it just for checking do you have a permission or not to open this url in mobile.